# usar variables de geolocation con otras funciones

Tags: javascript, async

Preciso usar latitud y longitud de la funcion de geolocation para usar con la siguiente funcion que es una api que muestra el clima basandose en la lat y lon, por asincronismo no puedo usar esas variables pero no encuentro como arreglarlo, queria consultar de que maneras podria resolverse gracias

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        lat =position.coords.latitude; 
        lon =position.coords.longitude;
    });
function WeatherForecast(lat,lon){
let key= "";
let url= 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat='+lat +'&lon='+lon+'&units=metric&appid='+key
fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data =>{ ...sigue el codigo...
```

Answer (score 0):

Para poder  ajustar en tiempo de respuesta tu función `WeatherForecas` a la **geolocation**  podrías realizar la llamada a la función dentro de tu función de localización, así no tendrás errores al sincronizar la respuesta.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
    
        lat =position.coords.latitude; 
        lon =position.coords.longitude;     
        
        WeatherForecast(lat,lon);
        
    });
    
function WeatherForecast(lat,lon){      
    let key= "";
    let url= 'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat='+lat +'&lon='+lon+'&units=metric&appid='+key;
    fetch(url)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data =>{ ...sigue el codigo...
}
```